# How can i get value of saldo (debit - kredit) Laravel-MySQL

Tags: mysql, laravel, for-loop, controller, accounting

> How can i get the value of saldo? Saldo = Debit - Kredit
> Im using laravel and MySQL, am i doing the counting in controller or in sql query?

[image: this is what table look like]

Comment: have you tried anything ? did you encounter errors ? or are you simply asking for someone to write your code for you ? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This question will be closed for **details of clarity**

Answer (score 0):

you can use DB::raw like this:

```
$values=\DB::table('myTable')->select('column1','column2',\DB::raw('Debit - Kredit as saldo') )->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

> I've solved the problem, here it is

```
SET @variable = 0;
UPDATE laporan_bukubesar
    SET saldo = (@variable := @variable + (`debit` - `kredit`))
    ORDER BY tanggal ASC;
```